# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When i run my site on mozilla i got this error above.Here some code snippet which might be helpful

```
<script src="http://www.iclubz.com/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.iclubz.com/js/readmore.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.iclubz.com/js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.iclubz.com/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.iclubz.com/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
```

But it's work fine on chrome.I don't know why this problem are showing.I'll helpful if anyone tell me the reason

Thanks in advance

**Edited** : i forgot to mention that all my javascript are called in the bollom of the page

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're including jQuery **at least** twice. It's not *the* problem, but it's *a* problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure to load jquery.js file before loading bootstrap.
This solved my problem.

Comment: wow really really thanks. i had change the order of loading scripts thus having trouble with my data-toggles ... you saved me of hours of debugging

Answer (score 0):

That error can only be caused by one of three things:

- Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
- You have a botched version of jQuery. This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.
- You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.
  You should check the Firebug net panel to see if the file is actually being loaded properly.

  If not, it will be highlighted red and will say "404" beside it. If the file is loading properly, that means that the issue is number 2.

Make sure all javascript code is being run inside a code block such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

Comment: 1.11.1 and 1.11.2 which are the ones included are not "very old" since the 1.x branch is still maintained. 1.11.2 is only about 6 months old. If you need to support IE 8 and below (which a lot of people still do) then you want the 1.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

Your first load jquery.js(min) then boostrap load

```
<script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more explanation to accompany your answer.

Comment: Type js tag on boostrap(tag)                                                                  
 <script src="/node_modules/jguery/dist/js/jguery.min.js"></script>       <script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>