# Using Javascript files in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core RC2 app in VS2015, I'm using [following example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_listgroup&stacked=h) of Collapsible List Groups that uses the following Javascript files. The example works fine in Visual Studio if I use the following scripts. But when I use the default javascipts installed in ASP.NET Core app (namely, `<script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` and 
    `<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`) the same example does not work. Are the above default Javascripts different than the following. What can I add to these defaults Javascripts to make the same example work? :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE** The location of the above example html file in my ASP.NET Core project is as shown below and the header of my html file looks like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>SideBar demo</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**My Html file location in ASP.NET Core project in VS2015**:

[image]

My bower.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": ">=1.8",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check for errors in console and you will see where browsers are looking for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue as follows:

1. I used Chrome Developer too to follow suggestion from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005253/using-javascript-files-in-asp-net-core#comment63480960_38005253) to look into the console and found the following error message: [Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32166065/1232087)
2. Then I followed [this user's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221636/1232087) to load jquery.js file before loading bootstrap files

Answer (score 1):

No, both are same. The first two links are downloaded bootstrap and jquery files and the rest are the online versions of the bootsrap and jquery.

Comment: But the same exmple is not working with the downloaded bootstrap and jquery files. I've added an UPDATE section to my post for further clarity.

Comment: What is not working? Did F12 give you any error information?

Comment: Inspect the page to get any information regarding the problem by F12 or Right click->Inspect.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts are probably outdated, try to update the bower.config file.

More info: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html

Comment: I had already gone through the link. It only shows how to add css or js files. I'm using the latest version `ASP.NET Core CR2` that already should have the latest default js and css files.

Comment: Which version jquery and bootstrap is using in bower.config?

Comment: Don't know if bower.config exists in VS2015 projects and what it is. But I've added **UPDATE 2** for you to show `bower.json` file.

Comment: It exists, it's in the root folder of your project.

EDIT: it's not bower.config, it's bower.json, my mistake.

Comment: Update jquery dependency to version to 1.12.2, it should work.